# Count records by date returning zero values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to find a way to output the number of records of each day between two given dates:

```
from = 7.days.ago.to_date
to = Date.today
total = Records.where(created_at: from..to).group("date(created_at)").count
list = total.values
```

There is just the problem that when in some dates are no records, it wouldn't be displayed, would be just ignored.

So instead of this:

```
list = [0,4,3,0,3,0,1]
```

I get this:

```
list = [4,3,3,1]
```

Well, I think I understand why I get it so, because of querying records and not dates after all.

I could do a loop `from.upto(to)` and on `each` one `do` a query to the DB, get those counts and build so my little list —or something else very *dirty*— but, is there a more clean solution not involving lots of queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not a perfect solution. But it doesn't involve any extra query. Basically reverse merge a hash with zero count for all the dates between from and to.

```
from = 7.days.ago.to_date
to = Date.today
date_hash = {}
(from..to).each{|date| date_hash[date] = 0}
total = Records.where(created_at: from..to).group("date(created_at)").count
total.reverse_merge!(date_hash)
```

Comment: Thank you. It works well. Just when I want to get just the values, using `values` method, it rearranges the zeros to the end. And I get `[4,3,3,1,0,0,0]` instead of `[0,4,3,0,3,0,1]`. Before doing `values` the order is correct.

Comment: What if you sort the hash before getting values. `Hash[total.sort].values`

Comment: Reverse merge adds the extra ones at the end. Atleast it did when i tested in console. That's why you saw all zero at the end. I would advise you to sort it anyways if you want your values array sorted based on the date